# load content from div and add it into another div within the same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an element  which contains some html content like this  :

`<span class="ecf-answer">Content here</span>` and another div where I want to load the 
content from the `span` element : 
`<div>Content taken from the span element </div>`.

Is this possible using jQuery ?

I've made a search here but I've found just methods on how to load div content from another page not from the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/MBc6h/)

```
$('#divID').html($('span.ecf-answer').html());
```

[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Also read [.append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) and [Dom insertion inside](http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/dom-insertion-inside/)

Comment: Thank you ! But is it possible once the content is retrieved to keep it there permanently and if the span element doesn't exist anymore to keep the content retrieved from it in the first place !?

Answer (score 1):

You will have to give your span and div an id. Once this is done it's pretty easy to do this just with JavaScript like this:

```
document.getElemenetById("divId").innerHTML = document.getElemenetById("spanId").innerHTML;
```

jQuery could be used but wouldn't add much value.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, for standard JS lovers like me:

```
document.getElementById("div2").innerHTML = document.getElementById("div1").innerHTML;
```

Where the `div2` is destination and `div1` the source...

**[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BUY84/)**

Answer (score 1):

Javascript works on the client side, so you can "move" the information in the same page, but the question is, when do you want to move it? On a button click?

You can use Javascript to load the original content in a hidden input like:

```
<span class="ecf-answer">Content here</span>
<input type="hidden" value="Content" id="originalContent">

and then:

function(){
 var content = document.getElementById('originalContent').value;
 document.getElementById('id').innerHTML = content;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
here is the html

<div id="divAddMe"></div>
<span id="spmMessage">
test me
</span>

//script to add the content from the span

$(function(){
   $("#divAddMe").html($("#spmMessage").text())
});
```